# Do we refer to certain archery styles as "qualitative shooting"?

Tags: archery, shooting

As I've read through [this page](http://en.yate.cz/arni-target-system-20-30-detail-TLT4000101.aspx), I stumbled across this quote:

> Notice: This type of target is intended for so called qualitative shooting, it is not intended for shooting with composite bows and crossbows.

What kinds of archery would be considered "qualitative shooting"? So, is "qualitative shooting" an official term to describe a bunch of disciplines (like traditional archery etc.)?

Comment: Perhaps "qualitative shooting" refers to low-power weapons, where what counts is where you hit the target, not whether it would be a certain kill. (E.g. a perfect shot on a deer would be pointless using a Daisy Red Ryder BB gun.) In this case using more powerful weapons might drastically reduce the life of the target.

Comment: @RayButterworth Ah I guess that could be it. Maybe like a synonym for "recreational".

Comment: Where did you get the "quality shooting" phrase from, when what you quote mentions "_qualitative_ shooting"?  They are far from synonyms, and _qualitative_ is often contrasted to _quantitative_.  Although I'm no archer, I might guess that it's a discipline that focuses more on style than on score.

Comment: This question is up for reopening but I feel it is a sport shooting question and should fit on the sport Stack, not on outdoors. In any case, it is to old to migrate. So if you want this question active, see if they accept  (these kinds of) shooting there.

Comment: I tried to look at the original page (in Czech) and googled the term they used "kvalitativní střílení". All results refer to the item mentioned in the link posted in the question. Looks very difficult to guess what they meant by that term

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, but I think the part about "did they want to make a joke" should be removed because that can only truly be answered by asking the person who wrote the original content (for others, it is opinion or conjecture). I also submitted an edit to fix that issue.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, you can vote to reopen so we can close for off topic, as this belongs on sport, but is too old to migrate.

Comment: This question was closed for valid reasons, as it stands today -- it should remain closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, is "quality shooting" an official term to describe a bunch of
> disciplines (like traditional archery etc.)?

No, de facto, I'd never met such interpretation even unofficially.

> Is it really true that we call these kinds of archery "quality
> shooting" or did they want to make a joke (mock compound and crossbow
> people)?

It looks like a strange phrase, yes. What are their reasons to mock customers with undecipherable bad jokes? They also have [targets](http://en.yate.cz/outdoor-45-xl-detail-TSA3000101.aspx) labeled for composite bows. So, the "so called" mockery is an assumption. So, here is my assumption, there is a comma instead of a dot.

> Notice:
> This type of target is intended for qualitative
> shooting.
>
> It is not intended for shooting with composite bows and crossbows.

In the video, they're using light bows with training arrows. Perhaps, most of the crossbows shred the target or displace it even with special bolts. Those who have written this, possibly, had a practice with them and just trying to help. Ask them for some clarifications.

Comment: Of course the "mockery" was an assumption. How would one think it's not? Thanks for your answer! :)